# Mode-within-group equivalent in Presto

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, presto

In Postgres, the following query outputs the most-frequently-purchased cheese for each customer:

```sql
SELECT
    customer,
    MODE() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "subcategory") AS "fav_cheese"
FROM dft
WHERE category = 'CHEESE'
GROUP BY
    customer
```

This returns:

```sh
customer   fav_cheese
       1      cheddar    # customer1's most-frequently-purchased cheese is cheddar
       2         blue    # customer2's most-frequently-purchased cheese is blue
       3     shredded    # customer3's most-frequently-purchased cheese is shredded
```

How to achieve the same output in Presto?

I've tried different methods with no success so far.

Comment: I think that actually is standard ANSI SQL

Comment: Possibly. Not supported by Presto in any case.

Comment: @Jivan . . . I am not aware that the relationship between PrestoDB and ANSI SQL is any stronger than any other database's relationship, so I adjusted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT customer, subcategory AS fav_cheese
FROM (SELECT customer, category, subcategory, COUNT(*) as cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM dft
      WHERE category = 'CHEESE'
      GROUP BY customer, category, subcategory
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. That is... heavy. What if we want to query that not from `dft` directly, but instead from a subquery like `select mode() from (select ... from dft) where category = 'cheese'`? Seems that it's going to need nesting yet another level

Comment: @Jivan . . . Yes, or use a CTE.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can use the histogram method:

```
SELECT customer, 
MAP_KEYS(hist)[
    ARRAY_POSITION(MAP_VALUES(hist), ARRAY_MAX(MAP_VALUES(hist)))
] as fav_cheese 
FROM (
   SELECT customer, histogram(subcategory) as hist
   FROM dft
   WHERE category = 'CHEESE'
   GROUP BY customer
) as f
```